# Upgrading packages with pip is not working properly

Tags: python, pip

I am using pip in Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8. I am trying to upgrade some packages and it seems to work since it does not give any error message. However, if I do `pip show` for the desired package, the version remains unchanged.

For instance, in the case of pip itself I am doing the following:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

And I am obtaining:

```
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-20.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-20.3.3
```

Then, when I try to check the installed version with `pip show pip`, I get the following:

```
Name: pip
Version: 20.0.2
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: pypa-dev@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: pip-upgrade
```

I have observed this problem also for scipy. However, I have been able to upgrade virtualenv and seaborn following the same procedure described above.

On the other hand, if I do the same upgrade process using `sudo` it does work. However, I would like to have the new versions installed not only for superuser.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple installations of Python on your system.

First provide the full name for Python 3.8 when installing pip to make sure it is installing pip for 3.8.

```
python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

You could also try to use the pip specifically for Python 3.8. It is usually called pip3.8.

It could also be the environment you are installing it in. It's better to use `pip --version` so that you know where it is pulling pip from, as well the version of Python being used.

```
pip3.8 --version
pip 20.3.3 from /home/eandersson/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

As you can see here depending on the user and env variables set it may be installed in a different location.

```
sudo pip3.8 --version
pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I would also recommend that you use a virtualenv if you need specific versions libraries installed for your project.

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pip --upgrade
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried options above and they did not help. I only have Python 3.8 and 2.7 installed, but the former is set as the default one, so I believe this is not the problem here.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567964/what-is-the-correct-way-to-upgrade-pip-in-stretch-debian

Comment: I strongly recommend you just use virtualenvs to be honest. It simplifies things a lot. If not feel free to post the result of `pip --version` and `pip3.8 --version`.

Comment: The outputs are ```pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)``` in both cases.